# Meanings of hosts, uris and methods when adding APIs

Tags: kong

I am following the [official tutorial](https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/getting-started/adding-your-api/) of Kong API Gateway.
The guide shows me how to create a simple API which points to http://httpbin.org

I have a few questions about the tutorial.

1. The guide demonstrate adding "--data 'hosts=example.com'". What does this line mean? Does this line mean, example.com is the allowed host to consume this API?
2. What actually does hosts, uris and methods mean in the [doc](https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/admin-api/#add-api)? I try create another API with "--data 'methods=GET'" instead of "--data 'hosts=example.com'". The difference I notice is, I don't need to use cURL to consume the API, but I can use any browser to consume the API.
3. Why the **target endpoint** (http://httpbin.org) is **upstream** instead of **downstream**? As I understand, in this case, Kong should be the upstream and the target endpoint should be the downstream...

> An upstream system is any system that sends data to the
>       Collaboration Server system. A downstream system is a system that
>       receives data from the Collaboration Server system. [reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWSR9_11.5.0/com.ibm.pim.dev.doc/integration/pim_con_dev_creatingjobsforintegrationcontainer.html)

Thanks all for your time!

Comment: See the Proxy Guide (which the tutorial links to) where all of this is documented: https://getkong.org/docs/latest/proxy/

Comment: Yes.. thank you for that!

Comment: @thibaultcha 's link is dead, this is my best guess as to what he linked: https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/latest/how-kong-works/routing-traffic/